# Get latitude and longitude in R using address

Tags: r, latitude-longitude

Is there a simple way in r to find the longitude and the latitude with the home addresses? Suriname just have on zipcode for all the adresses 00597.

This is the input:

| studentID | studentAddress | StudentCity | StudentCountry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gompertstraat 3 | Paramaribo | Suriname |
| 2 | Tourtonnelaan 3 | Paramaribo | Suriname |
| 3 | Sidodadieweg 3 | Saramacca | Suriname |
| 4 | Helena Christinaweg 3 | Wanica | Suriname |
| 5 | Bougainvillestraat 3 | Nickerie | Suriname |

The output should be:

| studentID | studentAddress | StudentCity | StudentCountry | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gompertstraat 3 | Paramaribo | Suriname | 5.851890 | -55.138220 |
| 2 | Tourtonnelaan 3 | Paramaribo | Suriname | 5.837420 | -55.152360 |
| 3 | Sidodadieweg 3 | Saramacca | Suriname | 5.798820 | -55.487570 |
| 4 | Helena Christinaweg 3 | Wanica | Suriname | 5.734510 | -55.241470 |
| 5 | Bougainvillestraat 3 | Nickerie | Suriname | 5.937410 | -56.986810 |

There should be a pretty straight forward way to do that. But I have no idea were to start in r.

Can somebody give me some instructions?

kind regards,

Comment: R does not ship with an inbuild database of geographic coordinates in Suriname. Have you looked for such a database, not necessarily linked with R?

Comment: Have a look at packages such as `tidygeocoder`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygeocoder)

address <- tribble(
  ~street, ~cty, ~country,
  "Gompertstraat 3", "Paramaribo", "Suriname",
  "Helena Christinaweg 3", "Wanica", "Suriname"
)
df <- address %>%
  geocode(street = street, city = cty, country = country, method = "osm")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you all, I will start using your suggestion.